# Unable to run my springboot web application

Tags: spring-boot

I have an `spring cloud` based project. When I run my application it shows the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'swaggerConfiguration' defined in class path resource [com/humatics/base/commons/swagger/autoconfigure/SwaggerAutoConfiguration.class]: 
    Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
        Failed to instantiate [io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig]: Factory method 'swaggerConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
            com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
```

Comment: Please show us your code and your dependencies.

Comment: It must be due to an old version guava library. Try using lates version of guava library https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava